# HIVE SQL to extract Record as JSON

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have a table in Hive with multiple fields.  For example

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|Primary Key|Attribute 1|Attribute 2|Attribute 3|Attribute 4|
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to query the table using HIVE SQL and return a JSON object embedded in a CSV format.  For example:

```
Primary Key, Attribute 1, {"Primary Key":"", "Attribute 2":"",  "Attribute 2":""}, Attribute 4
```

I don't have any post query programming language to convert the values to JSON format. I have no problem with straight SQL, I just don't know if I can get the JSON object out using sql.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used `brickhouse JAR (brickhouse-0.6.0.jar)` for `JSON` output to achieve something like this. This is the best jar available, but if we need the keys in the `JSON` to preserve `camelcases`, then an extra elemennt need to be put in the `to_json(named_struct())` clause.

You can read more about this JAR [here](https://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/hive-and-json-made-simple/). Below is the code snippet on how I did it.

```
ADD JAR path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.6.0.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION to_json AS 'brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF'; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS V2
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
SELECT
    empId,
    to_json(named_struct('camel_case', 1, 'employee_id', employeeId, 'manager_id', msgId, 'org_Id', orgId), true) AS jsonString
FROM 
    employee
WHERE 
    employeeId=101
);
```

The output would be like this:

```
101, {"camelCase" : true, "employeeId" : 101, "managerId" : 201, "orgId" : 301}
```

I had to handle the case where I had to deal with `Array of JSON` elements which needed to be in square brackets(`[]`). You can ignore outermost layer in the below query (i.e. `SELECT FROM y` and just use the queries till `SELECT FROM x`) if you are sure you have single `JSON` per record. Query change for handling `Array of JSON`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS V2
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
AS 
SELECT 
    y.employeeId, CONCAT('[', y.jsonData, ']') AS jsonData
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        x.employeeId, collect_list(jsonString) AS jsonData 
    FROM (
    SELECT
    empId,
    to_json(named_struct('camel_case', 1, 'employee_id', employeeId, 'manager_id', msgId, 'org_Id', orgId), true) AS jsonString
    FROM 
        employee
    WHERE 
        employeeId=101
    ) x
    GROUP BY 
        x.employeeId
) y;
```

The output would be like this:

```
101, [{"camelCase" : true, "employeeId" : 101, "managerId" : 201, "orgId" : 301}]
```

You can tweak this query to put the data in `HDFS` directly using this version:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/path/of/target/directory/'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'AS 
SELECT ...
```